# C# DispatcherOperation loop never breaks

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispatcher

Can some one please explain why this loop never 'breaks' and goes on forever please? How do I tell the program to recheck the status? All I want to do is not progress until the status changes. Thanks

```
DispatcherOperation dis = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    updateTextBox(i.ToString());
    dis = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new Action(delegate
        {
            //yes, do nothing at all!!
        }
    ));
}

while(dis.Status != DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed)
{                 
}
```

Comment: Is this a WinForms/WPF project? Is this code inside an event handler? Can you give some context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing this on the same thread as the dispatcher is meant to run on, your infinite, unyielding loop effectively shuts out the dispatcher from ever being able to dispatch the call. You should not loop like this anyway - at the very least put a Sleep in the loop.

Comment: This has now solved a printing issue I've had for about 3 weeks!!!!! Beers are on me for this, thank you.